# Center text and float div to the right

Tags: css, html, styles

I have a container div which has text within it that I want centered. I want to also insert a div into the container which floats to the right, like this:

```
<div id="container" style="text-align:center">
  Text
  <div id="child" style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately what happens is that the text is no longer centered with respect to the container, but is instead shifted to the left by the width of the child.

Does anyone know how to get the text to center whilst keeping the div contained to the right?

Comment: No, although it will very rarely change width.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this...

```
<div style='position:relative;'>
  my centered text
  <div style='position:absolute;right:0;top:0'>
    my right div
  </div>
</div>
```

You can obviously throw the inline styles into CSS.

Comment: just keep in mind the "absolute" div will render above your "centered" text, if the centered text is too long.

Comment: Excellent. I tried this but wasn't aware that there was a "right" attribute! I thought I'd have to resort to using JavaScript which would be a nuissance for something as simple as this. By the way, your answer can be improved by including top:0; as well so that it aligns it with the containing div.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posibly this??   Creating 3 equal parts. left middle and right??

```
<div id="container">
<div id="child1" style="float:right width: 30px;"></div>
<div id="child2" style="float:right width: 30px; text-align:center;">TEXT</div>
<div id="child3" style="float:right width: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would indeed work, but is there a tidier solution (one that does not require 2 extra divs)?

Comment: You could float the one right, and float #2 (with text) to the right, and forget #3, just set `container` to a width of 90px maintaining that the other two are still set to 30